# How to express the sentence in the question

Tags: word-request

I want to say the designers of a system have considered(*) two goals for it, and I want to mention the goals in a passive way, as shown in the following sentence:

Two goals are ..... for this system, which are A and B.

1. Is the above sentence correct and idiomatic?
2. If yes, how should the blank be filled? i.e. which verb should be used?

   ---

   (*) I don't know if "to consider" is the right verb to use, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You could say **envisioned**.

Comment: "Consider" gives the idea there is a choice, and that choice has not been made yet. Is that the case?

Comment: @GabrielLuci No indeed. I want to say the design is already done, and the decisions are already made.

Comment: A goal is like a compass bearing: it specifies which way you go. you **set** the goal, and then carry on in that direction.

Comment: This isn't an exact answer to your question, but I would rephrase your sentence as 'This system has two goals, A and B.' I believe that makes it clear that the goals are not subject to being changed. If the design of the system was created with certain goals in mind, then I would say 'This system design has two goals, power efficiency and low maintenance.' The system can have a purpose independent of the goals the system designers had when creating their design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many words that can fit well in this blank. One of them is **set**, if the goals are already set in stone. If the designers are yet thinking about the goals, I think you should use **estimated**, **thought** or, as you mentioned, **considered**, and also many other synonyms for these words.

Answer (score 1):

As Joao Arruda mentioned, you could use "set" to indicate the goals have been decided on.

Or "Two goals have been decided on..."

Or "We've chosen to work towards two goals..."

Or "Our goals for this system are..."

Words like "considered", "envisioned", "estimated", "thought" give the impression that no decisions have been made.